# How to share video URL to all apps (Whatsapp, Facebook etc)?

Tags: android

How to share video  URL to all apps  in android (Whats app, Facebook etc)?
 By applying below code,  I am facing "File Format not supported error"?

```
enter code here





ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
    content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "http://www.demonuts.com/Demonuts/smallvideo.mp4");
    ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:"));
```

Comment: "http://www.demonuts.com/Demonuts/smallvideo.mp4" is not a file path

Answer (score 0):

First, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) states that the value for `EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to be a `Uri` with a `content:` scheme, which means it points to a `ContentProvider`. Apps implementing `ACTION_SEND` *might* support other schemes, but they do not have to, and in particular they do not have to support `http`.

Second, use a real MIME type, not a wildcard. You are *supplying* the content; you should know its MIME type.

Third, as others pointed out in comments, `http://www.demonuts.com/Demonuts/smallvideo.mp4` is not a filesystem path. It is a URL. Use `Uri.parse("http://www.demonuts.com/Demonuts/smallvideo.mp4")` to get that in the form of a `Uri`.